# Handling inheritance with OpenAPI (and the code generators)

Tags: openapi, openapi-generator

I'm working on an API as a springboot project. I work with OpenAPI, design-first and am facing the following challenge: I need to get the openapi description in such a way that the OpenAPI generator (Spring) will generate a controller interface like this:

```
ResponseEntity<? extends Object> pushVersions()
```

So far, I have only been able to generate something like this:

```
ResponseEntity<Object> pushVersions()
```

Comment: Please post the relevant part of your OpenAPI specification, thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can use the x-parent attribute in the spec to extend:
https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator/pull/14172
in combination with the allOf
You don't even need to use an discriminator for that

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).